# Website progress storage?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to web development and have for most of you trivial question.Where and how to store website progress user did? I mean...for example.We have javascript variable

`var a=0;`

and

`<div id="clickhere" onClick="a=a+1;document.getElementById('clickhere').innerHTML=a">`

.Imagine someone clicked on that division once and leaves website.I want him to see displayed number one in that div after returning to website.

Comment: Per user or total all user clicks?

Comment: Each user would see his progress independently.

Comment: We'll this needs to be broken down into 2 steps. 1. Identify unique users. 2. Persist visit data. To persist data you can either use html5 local storage, or to make it visible to an admin or site owner, persist it to a server side storage mechanism (database.)

Comment: Since the tags include only javascript and html so i think you can use a cookie for this.But the problem with cookie is that if a user deletes it then the data stored will also be deleted.

Comment: Thank you.Cookies could be what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Are you only using JavaScript? Or could you use a server side language such as php or .net?

Answer (score 3):

You either need a server side to store this data, identify the client by some uid or login and retrive the data on repeated visit. or a simpler solution, use a client side cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want visit data viewable to each individual user, you can use a local storage mechanism. For clients whose browsers support HTML 5 you can use localstorage to store a retrieve the variable between user visits. You could get he JavaScript to set a cookie and then check if a cookie exists per user visit, if it does, increment the visit count.

A more robust solution would be to persist the visit count server side. You can issue a cookie to a user, on each future visit, you can either send the visit data to the server via Ajax, or by form submit. This would then need to be persisted to a database using a server side language such as php, ruby or .net.